# Specifiy Unix TimeStamp Range in Parameter

Tags: bash, wildcards

I am launching a mrjob in bash and need to pass in as parameters a range of gz files which have unix time stamps in them as: `filename_9127381923.gz`. How to do this in the simplest possible way? I can pass in multiple file parameters, luckily.

Range:

> 1413324000 (Wednesday 0:00)
>
> 1413410400 (Thursday 0:00)

pseudo example:

`$python my_mrjob.py 1413324000-1413410400.gz`

Answer (score 2):

Use the range operator:

```
echo {1413324000..1413324199}.gz
```

Similarly,

```
$python my_mrjob.py {1413324000..1413324199}.gz
```

If files are not there for every milli second:

```
$python my_mrjob.py  $(ls {1413324000..1413324199}.gz 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: If this works you are the man.

Comment: I should say that these are unix timestamps and we dont have a file for every millisecond, meaning there are holes in that iteration. `ls somename_{1413324000..1413410400}.gz` yields a lot of "file or directory" not found, before the wanted files will be printed out.

Comment: Updated for your requirememnt

Comment: Thanks, but you sure that syntax is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not as simple, but my 'weapon of choice'

```
python my_mrjob.py $(
for f in {1413324000..1413410400}; do [ -f filename_$f.gz ] && echo $f; done
)
```

PS: IMHO, the python job itself should be modified to allow for range entry, with additional intelligence to skip over non existent files. Will be much faster and simpler. The {a..b} syntax is not a lazy iterator; it actually generates all the numbers, passing them to the 'for' statement. This might result in running out of env space.

Answer (score 0):

Make some fake test files: (only for this example)

```
$ touch filename_{1000000000..1000000099..5}.gz
```

Grab a "time" range of files from `ls` output and pass this to `echo`:

```
$ echo $(ls | awk -F'[_,]' '1000000044<=$2 && $2<=1000000066')
```

filename_1000000045.gz filename_1000000050.gz filename_1000000055.gz filename_1000000060.gz filename_1000000065.gz

Substitute `echo` with your `$python` call as needed.